# SharePoint 2010 - cannot Create New Connection (Configure Synchronization Connections)

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to configure User Profile Service Application and it's very complicate. I'm following instructions from this link :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#ConfigSyncProc

I started User Profile Service Application and its current status is "running".

However, when I try to create new connection, it says that User Profile Service Application is not running and that I shall start the application.

I really dont have any idea how to fix that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your farm account is not local administrator. [Check Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) by Spencer Harbar.

Follow these instructions from start to end and everything will be okey. For the given problem check **Start the UPS related SharePoint Services** section of the article above.

Comment: Farm account is member of Administrators group.

Comment: :(, some other ideas: Have you followed instructions in the article step-by-step, have you applied August CU?

Comment: Yes, i did. I also have applied August CU. Now I'm reading tutorial again.